# PHP script not grabbing 'phone number' value from form

Tags: php

My Contact form doesnt email the phone number. I have the field in the form and in the script also.

```
<form id="contact" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name" id="name_label">Name <br /></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  value="" class="text-input" />
        <label for="email" id="email_label">E-mail<br /></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  value="" class="text-input" />
        <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Phone number<br /></label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  value="" class="text-input" />
        <label for="msg" id="msg_label">Preferred contact time</label>
        <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="msg" id="msg" ></textarea> <br class="clear" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send Message &rarr;"/>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

and the following PHP script:

```
<?php 
    $emailTo = 'test@test.co.uk';
    $subject = 'Advanced Contact Form';
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
    $msg=$_REQUEST['msg'];

    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nphone: $phone \n\nMessage: $msg";
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    echo 'Mail sent';
?>
```

The email sends fine but the phone number doesnt show up in the email.
Any ideas what the issue could be?

**EDIT: my url looks like this:**

```
www.website.com/contact.html?name=test&email=test%40test.com&phone=0112+2255555&msg=2312312312312&submit=Send+Message+%26%238594%3B
```

Comment: check the spelling in actual code also, at first look cannt find any mistake

Comment: Do not use `$_REQUEST` if at all possible. It's not as safe as specifing `POST` or `GET`.

Comment: @Arun, then why did you bother to answer?

Comment: Add a sample email that you actually receive to the question.

Comment: How are you entering the phone number into the field? What special characters are you using? Like parenthesis, hyphens, etc.

Comment: try just `echo $phone . '<br />' . $_POST['phone'] ;` to see what each of those variables is holding.

Comment: i am writting - "0112 22222222"

Comment: Looks okay to me. Try doing a `print_r($_REQUEST)` and make sure `phone` isn't set twice (could be once in a cookie and once via the form?)

Comment: Change `mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);` to `    var_dump($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers,$_REQUEST);` and put the output here lets see what you are dealing with

Comment: Also something you should watchout for is header injection on that last `$email`

Comment: What does a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` show? If the phone value isn't in there, then PHP isn't receiving it to begin with.

Comment: var_dump didnt show anything on the page. my page says `Contact Form Submitted! We will be in touch soon.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how you should process a form for email, first process the values and build upon an error array if any.

Then send, **NEVER Trust user input especially contact forms.**

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$emailTo = 'test@test.co.uk';
$subject = 'Advanced Contact Form';

$name=(isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:null);
$email=(isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:null);
$phone=(isset($_POST['phone'])?$_POST['phone']:null);
$msg=(isset($_POST['msg'])?$_POST['msg']:null);

$error=array();
$cont=true;
//name
if(isset($name)){
    if(strlen($name)<=1){
        $cont=false;
        $error['error_name']='Enter your real name!';
    }else{
        $name=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\:\?.\&,_ -]/s', '', $name);
    }
}else{
    $error['error_name']='Enter your name!';
    $cont=false;
}

//email
if(isset($email)){
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

    }else{
        $cont=false;
        $error['error_email']='Email Invalid';
    }
}else{
    $cont=false;
    $error['error_email']='Please enter your email!';
}

//phone
if(isset($phone)){
    if(strlen($phone)<=1){
        $cont=false;
        $error['error_phone']='Enter your real number!';
    }else{
        $phone=preg_replace('/[^0-9]/s', '', $phone);
    }
}else{
    $error['error_phone']='Enter your number!';
    $cont=false;
}

//message
if(isset($msg)){
    if(strlen($msg)<=1){
        $cont=false;
        $error['error_message']='Enter your real message!';
    }else{
        $msg=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\:\?.\&,_ -]/s', '', $msg);
    }
}else{
    $error['error_message']='Enter your message!';
    $cont=false;
}

if(empty($error) && $cont ==true){
    //send mail
    $body = "Name: $name \n\n
         Email: $email \n\n
         phone: $phone \n\n
         Message: $msg";

    // Additional headers
    $headers ='MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
    $headers.='Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";
    $headers.='From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>'."\r\n";
    $headers.="X-Mailer: Remote Mail\r\n";
    // Mail it
    $status = (mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers))?'Mail Was Sent':'Error Sending email';
}else{

  //error with form values
  $status='';
  foreach($error as $type=>$reason){
    $status .= $reason.'<br />';
  }
}

//Echo your form or status page
echo $status;
}else{
    //Echo your form
}

?>
```

Comment: This php doesnt send emails.. I have tested this.. :(

Comment: This didnt work but ill accept the answer anyway, as you have shown me extra things to help me in my journey. Thank you